# How correctly sort an array?

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I have this code for sort array `polsum`:

```
int comp (const void * a, const void * b){   
   double aa = *(double*)a, bb = *(double*)b;

   if (aa < bb) return -1;
   if (aa > bb) return  1;
   return 0;
}

double sort(double *polsum){                              
    int p;
    qsort(polsum, sizeof(double),sizeof(double), comp);
    return 0;
}
```

But output is:

```
5,01/
80,86/
85,01/
85,01/
300,88/
600,88/
77888,88/
100400,00/
670,88/
80,86/
80,86/
```

Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: You're not showing us your full code.

Answer (score 1):

Your passing in sizeof(double) for the count of elements to be sorted.  sizeof(double) == 8

Consider adding the following to your sort function:

```
double sort(double *polsum, int count) {
    int p;
    qsort(polsum, count, sizeof(double), comp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but why? how can I repair this please? I really don't know

Comment: Your passing in an array of doubles, you should, at some point know how many elements there are.  You should pass in the number of elements to your sort function.